# Get all the infos of a db used in another Bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle

I'm not sure the title is clear enough. I'll explain better :
I use 2 Bundles in my project, MenuBundle and IntranetBundle.

MenuBundle is here to build the navigation on the left and the other Bundle is for the entire website.

My problem is that I want to check if one of the users in the database (the table is used by the entity, the controller etc.. on the IntranetBundle) is having his birthday birthday and then change the color of an element on the navigation part.

But I don't know how to call the users and how to check if one is having his birthday (the method is already created in the IntranetBundle, I used it when it's required for other stuff but only in the IntranetBundle, I just don't know how to call the method and check it in MenuBundle)

Here is the beginning of the Builder (the end is not useful for my problem) :

```
namespace Osaxis\MenuBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class Builder extends ContainerAware
{
public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
{
    $route = $this->container->get('request')->get('_route');
    $menu = $factory->createItem('root');

    $menu->addChild('Accès', array('route' => 'logout'));
    $menu['Accès']->setAttribute('class', 'menuGcheLevel1'.($route == 'login' ? ' On' : ''));

    // si l'utilisateur est authentifie (non anonyme)
    $security = $this->container->get('security.context');
    if ($security->getToken() !== null && $security->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {

        /** @var \Osaxis\IntranetBundle\Entity\Users $user */
        $user = $security->getToken()->getUser();

        // Gestion des congés
        if ($security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            $menu->addChild('Gestion des congés', array('route' => 'admin_conge'));
            $menu['Gestion des congés']->setAttribute('class', 'menuGcheLevel1'.(fnmatch('admin_conge*', $route) ? ' On' : ''));
        } else if (!$user->getUsrStagiaire() && $user->getUsrRol()->getRolCode() != 'ROLE_CONSULTATION') {
            $menu->addChild('Gestion des congés', array('route' => 'conge'));
            $menu['Gestion des congés']->setAttribute('class', 'menuGcheLevel1'.(fnmatch('conge*', $route) ? ' On' : ''));
        }

        // Gestion des jours fériés et Equipe Osaxis
        if ($security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            $menu->addChild('Gestion des jours fériés', array('route' => 'jours_feries_index'));
            $menu['Gestion des jours fériés']->setAttribute('class', 'menuGcheLevel1'.(fnmatch('jours_feries_*', $route) ? ' On' : ''));

            $menu->addChild('Equipe Osaxis', array('route' => 'users_index'));
            $menu['Equipe Osaxis']->setAttribute('class', 'menuGcheLevel1'.(fnmatch('users_*', $route)?  ' On' : ''));
            if (fnmatch('users_*', $route) && !fnmatch('users_changePwd', $route)) {
                $menu->addChild('Gestion des utilisateurs', array('route' => 'users_index'));
                $menu['Gestion des utilisateurs']->setAttribute('class', 'menuGcheLevel2'.(fnmatch('users_*', $route) && !fnmatch('users_trombi*', $route) && !fnmatch('users_reunions*', $route) ? ' On' : ''));
                $menu->addChild('Trombinoscope', array('route' => 'users_trombi'));
                $menu['Trombinoscope']->setAttribute('class', 'menuGcheLevel2'.(fnmatch('users_trombi*', $route) ? ' On' : ''));
                $menu->addChild('Réunions délégués', array('route' => 'users_reunions'));
                $menu['Réunions délégués']->setAttribute('class', 'menuGcheLevel2'.(fnmatch('users_reunions*', $route) ? ' On' : ''));
            }

        }

        if($user->isBirthday()){
            echo "test";
        }
```

The "if" at the end is just testing the user who is logged.

I wanna know if any of the users is having his birthday today.

I hope I gave all the necessary details.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Do you want to check if a user has his/her birthday today? What does `isBirthday()` do?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do, but everything about the users is in IntranetBundle. And the method is just returning true if the user calling the method is having his birthday today. isBirthday() works, I use it in the IntranetBundle to make changes if it's someone birthday. I just want to do changes as well in the other Bundle. But I don't know how to use it

Comment: What's the  `$user` variable returning? If it's returns the current user, what's the problem with calling `if ($user->isBirthday)`? I assume that `isBirthday()` is a method in class `\Osaxis\IntranetBundle\Entity\Users`?

Comment: BTW, you can increase the readability or your question by removing all irrelevant if/else-statements. I don't think it necessary for us to know the exact menu tree ;)

Comment: Because it's only the user logged who can see it's his birthday. I want to add colors on "Equipe Osaxis" so that everyone can see it's someone's birthday and go see who it is. So it must check all the users and if one is having his birthday then something changes in the menu. Should I put this better explanation on my question ? Yes the method is in this Entity

Comment: Ah! You want to see if any of our users has it's birthday today?

Comment: Yes, that's it ^^ Should I call the other Bundle in any way or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found an other way without doing weird stuff with expression.
Here it is :

```
$repo = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getRepository('IntranetBundle:Users');

        $users = $repo->findAll();

        for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($users); $i++){
            if($users[$i]->isBirthday()){
                echo 'un anniv '. $users[$i];
            }
        }
```

With that I can get how many people are having their birthday and which ones.